# Barcode font is working fine on develipment machine but not on client machine

Tags: fonts, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, barcode

I am working on bar code reader in one of the application. I am printing the bar codes in the few reports. I am using the free font IDAutomationHC39M. Guys it works fine on my development machine but not on client machine. i.e. when i load the report on my development system it works fine but when i load the same report on client machine the bar code is not shown. Can somebody  help me what can be the reason?

**Facts**:
- I am using MS VS 2005.
- I am using the free font IDAutomationHC39M.
- The font is installed on client machine manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install IDAutomation COM component on client computer? (At least package, which we use, does use special COM dll to create Crystal user functions to manage barcode fonts.)